# snap perpendicular to an edge/line like in CAD

Tags: snapping

I want to add an edge from A to B and i want the line to be perpendicular to the target edge. so it should make 90 deg angle like in the image. How to do this ? do i need addons ? Does anyone know the good one ?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: its simple if your edge is aligned with one of the axes otherwise you could have more trouble and may need an addon. I will have to think about this

Comment: https://blendermarket.com/products/snap-utilities this is a good addon, but it seems that it's not working in 2.8.

Answer (score 1):

It can be frustrating in other ways, but this just happens to be what the Blender snap system does without add-ons.

- Set snap to 'Vertex' and 'Active'
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> Create a Custom Orientation from side B. (Check 'Use after creation')
- <kbd>K</kbd> Cut an edge from side A to side B
- With Snap on,  <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd>move point B up and down its edge

When you hover over point A, it will snap to  the point on side B from which a perpendicular is dropped to it.

What if the new edge isn't in the right place?

- Cut *another* edge, and  <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> slide it up and down the face, making the edge parallel to the correctly oriented one by hitting  <kbd>E</kbd>, and  <kbd>F</kbd> if necessary.

Comment: @susu  How did that happen, and not get wiped by admin? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thought I might add an answer considering Blender's new updates.

Considering the following trapezoidal prism, where you want to add a line from side A to side B, such that the line is perpendicular to side B, as shown below:
[image: basic layout]

First, head into *edit mode*, and start by enabling *auto merge vertices*, located on the top right:
[image: automerge]

Then click the *options* menu that's right beside it, and enable *split edges & faces*. This will allow us to automatically split a face when we draw a line across it, as shown in the later steps.

Now, to start drawing the line, add a point on side A. You can do that by subdividing the edge, and sliding the vertex to your desired place (by double clicking G).

Next, go to the snapping menu up above, and select *snap to edge perpendicular*. Below, you can select any of the *snap with* options, like *closest*, *center* or *median* - the only note is that if you're selecting *center*, make sure your *transform pivot point* is anything **but** the *cursor*. Finally, make sure you have *project to self* enabled, as this will allow us to snap to the object itself. Also if you didn't already, make sure you have *snap during transform* ON (the magnet).
[image: snap menu]

Finally, select the vertex on side A, and click E to *extrude*, and extend it to side B, and you should see it snap.
[image: snap]

Comment: This should be the new selected answer.